# Couldn't transfer dependancies from maven when running from Jenkins

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I have a script in Java, I could run it with maven commands locally and even in the local Jenkins setup (localhost)

Same set of scripts when I try to run from company jenkins server, it throws an error as this :

- [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: unknown error -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR]*

Note :
I setup the jenkins server from ansible playbook, and the pipeline script is as follows:

```
    node {
  def mvnHome
  stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
     // Get some code from a GitHub repository
     git branch: '*/work', credentialsId: 'git-deploy', url:'<correct git url>'
  }
  stage('Build') {
     // Run the maven build
        docker.image("maven:3.2-jdk-8").inside("--privileged=true -e TZ=Asia/Singapore") {
           sh 'mvn --version'
           sh 'which mvn'
           sh "'/usr/bin/mvn' clean test"
        }

  }
```

What could be the cause? please help.

Comment: 'Unknown host' error indicates there may be an issue with DNS. What do you see when you curl the repo endpoint?

Comment: Hi, this is what I see when curl :                                                        
 <html>
<head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body>
<h1>302 Moved Temporarily</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: Found</li>
<li>Message: Resource Found</li>
<li>RequestId: 962A7C8D93DFC4FF</li>
<li>HostId: azwOUarJzTv13ic/1nehAgQVba2RU06i2QopsL/hpwuftTRRGBZp9lW98YDxXz7f5XozIvN+7tA=</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Try `curl -L https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` to follow the redirect. As @anil mentions in his answer, there's possibly a proxy between your server and Maven central that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a proxy issue.

Your `Maven` setup is unable to download the `maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar`.

Try to download the jar file manually in the machine where Jenkins is installed. Open the following link in the browser:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar

If you are able to download it here, then check your browser's proxy and try to use the same proxy in  the `settings.xml` of your `maven`.

Example:

```
<proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Check this [guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for proxy settings in Maven.

Comment: Hi, I copied the maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar and put it into the failed location. Error remains the same

Comment: @AJano is the proxy setting correct? If it is, then clear `.m2` folder to clear out the old dependencies and run the build again.

Comment: it stays the same.